# Ubuntu 18.04 how to install AMD driver for Wani Radeon R5 R6 R7 Graphics?

Tags: 18.04, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I run the command

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

and this was the the output.

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] (rev e2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Carrizo
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

I would like to install the correct graphics drivers. I haven't seen Carrizo before. Which drivers to install?

I also saw this post but there was no answer.
[Exact AMD GPU model is ambigious](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187654/exact-amd-gpu-model-is-ambigious)

I also run this command

```
lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
```

This is the output

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] (rev e2)
```

How to proceed?